# Powershell Code is working well on Powershell.exe and Powershell ISE but not working on VS Code

Tags: json, powershell, json.net, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to validate Json against Schema using Powershell and Newtonsoft dlls. My script is working well as expected if I run it on Powershell.exe or Powershell ISE but it isn't working if I run it using VS Code (on same PC).

```
$Json_file = "D:\Json\file_sample.json"
$Json_file_wrong = "D:\Json\file_sample_wrong.json"
$Json_Schema_file = "D:\Json\schema_sample.json"

$Json = Get-Content $Json_file
$Json_wrong = Get-Content $Json_file_wrong
$SchemaJson = Get-Content $Json_Schema_file

$Json_dll = "D:\Json\Json110r1\Bin\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
$Json_Schema_dll = "D:\Json\JsonSchema30r9\Bin\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.dll"

Add-Type -Path $Json_dll
Add-Type -Path $Json_Schema_dll

$source = @'
    public class Validator
    {
        public static System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> Validate(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken token, Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema schema)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> messages;
            Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions.IsValid(token, schema, out messages);

            return messages;
        }
    }
'@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -ReferencedAssemblies $Json_dll, $Json_Schema_dll

function Validate_Json_Against_Schema {
    param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] $Json_param,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] $Schema_param
    )
$valid = $false

$Token = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]::Parse($Json_param)
$Schema = [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]::Parse($Schema_param)

$result = [Validator]::Validate($Token,$Schema)

if ($result.Count -eq 0)
    {
    $valid = $true
    }
return $valid
}

Validate_Json_Against_Schema $Json $SchemaJson
Validate_Json_Against_Schema $Json_wrong $SchemaJson
```

If I run it using VS Code (version 1.12.1, Powershell extension version 1.6.0) I have such error:

```
Cannot convert argument "token", with value: "{
  "shipping_address": {
    "street_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC"
  }
}", for "Validate" to type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken": "Cannot convert the "{
  "shipping_address": {
    "street_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC"
  }
}" value of type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject" to type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken"."
At C:\Users\popovvg\Desktop\123.ps1:39 char:1
+ $result = [Validator]::Validate($Token,$Schema)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

My OS is fully updates Windows 10 x64. $PSVersionTable

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                               
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.98                                                                                                                        
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                             
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                             
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.98                                                                                                                       
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                     
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Json file:

```
{
  "shipping_address": {
    "street_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC",
    "type": "business"
  }
}
```

Schema file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    }
  },

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
        { "properties":
          { "type": { "enum": [ "residential", "business" ] } },
          "required": ["type"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to run it on Windows 7 x86 - same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug I recall hearing in VS Code and PowerShell extension around classes, but can't recall what it was. Your script is being executed in VS Code via the Integrated Terminal, which is PowerShell Editor Services in the back end.

The host that your code executes in that integrated terminal is a different host than what you get via PowerShell.exe or the ISE. I would recommend submitting an issue with the VS Code logs to the PS Extension repo: https://github.com/powershell/vscode-powershell/issues

Comment: Thanks! I created bug request on VSCode github: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1267